# how to create a sql connection and how to create .sql file and migration scripts in docker?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

We are developing a sample poc on microservices. We stuck at sql connection with docker. How to create migration scripts and .sql file how can we deploy those scripts in docker.  Can any one give some demo and code on it.

Comment: What is running on docker ? SQL Server ? In that case you can just connect using normal connectionstrings, all you need to know is the ipaddress where your sql server is running on

Comment: Maybe this can help you somewhat https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @GuidoG if you dont know means dont comment it.

Answer (score 0):

So if your server is outside the docker (what is the only reasonable thing). You could do it using a docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
ARG connectionString
ENV CONNECTION_STRING=$connectionString
COPY ["*********.csproj", "*********/"]
RUN dotnet restore "*********.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/*********"
RUN dotnet build "*********" -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet ef database update <------ HERE 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "*********" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PROD
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "*********"]
```

the

> RUN dotnet ef database update

(if you are not using .net core, then few things might change.)

in your startup project you should have something like:

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "PROD")
        {
            return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING");
        }
        else
        {
            return @"Server=.;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        }

    }
}

public UsersDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UsersDbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);

    return new UsersDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

inside

`public class XXXXXContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<XXXXXDbContext>`

and at the end when you run

`- docker build -f xxxxxx/Dockerfile -t xxxxx.azurecr.io/xxxxx:latest . --build-arg connectionString="some connection string"`

you docker build should complete the migration process

Comment: i created migrations and  how can i deploy those migration scripts  in docker